# How to access the LayoutManager from the RecyclerView's ItemDecoration class?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I haven't been able to find any post about it...

We have the good old [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) code (taken from [Suleiman's Mansonry Github project](https://github.com/Evin1-/Masonry/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/grafixartist/masonry/SpacesItemDecoration.java)):

```
public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final int mSpace;

    public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
        this.mSpace = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.left = mSpace;
        outRect.right = mSpace;
        outRect.bottom = mSpace;

        // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0)
            outRect.top = mSpace;
    }
}
```

I want to have a condition that sets `mSpace` (offset/margin) depending on the current [LayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) in the [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

For example:

```
if(/* LayoutManager is LinearLayoutManager*/){
   //Set larger margin
}else{
   //Set lower margin
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... as I was *re-reading* the question to check if anything was missing, and I realized that you actually get a RecyclerView reference (parent) as an argument of [getItemOffsets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html#getItemOffsets(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.view.View,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State)).

So you can just call `parent.getLayoutManager()` from inside the function.

**Example:**

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

    if (parent.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager){
        margin = 2;
    }else if (parent.getLayoutManager() instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager){
        margin = 1;
    }else{
        margin = 0;
    }

    //Do magic
}
```